# Use WP meta value within PHP function

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I am trying to display content in a wordpress post from an RSS feed.  I'd like to be able to enter the RSS URL into a Wordpress post so that the feed content can change from post to post.

I can create the desired output using this code and by directly entering in an RSS url where is says 'ENTER RSS URL HERE'

```
    <?php
    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load('ENTER RSS URL HERE');
    $feed = array();
    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        $item = array ( 
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            );
        array_push($feed, $item);
    }
    $limit = 6;
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
        $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
        $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
        $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
                echo '<div class="product-item">';
        echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
            echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
                echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

And I can also output a URL entered as a post meta value like this:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'RSS', true); ?>
```

I'm just unsure how I can combine the two so that the RSS URL can be changed dynamically. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following

```
<?php
global $post;
$url = ((filter_var(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'RSS', true), FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) ? get_post_meta($post->ID, 'RSS', true) : 'fallback url');
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load($url);
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node)
{
    $item = array(
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    );
    array_push($feed, $item);
}
$limit = 6;
for ($x = 0; $x < $limit; $x++)
{
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    echo '<div class="product-item">';
    echo '<p>' . $description . '</p>';
    echo '<p><strong><a href="' . $link . '" title="' . $title . '">' . $title . '</a></strong><br />';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Igor! It was working on the fall back URL only so I removed the FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL (not sure if I was meant to replace that with something?) and it's doing exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If the RSS-URL is always inside the post metadata, you could simply use that:

```
$rss->load(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'RSS', true));
```

Or do I get something wrong on your question?

Comment: Thanks Christian - that is what I want to achieve however it doesn't seem to work... am I missing something else? When I enter this in dreamweaver it says there's a syntax error on this line. When I try it on Wordpress is breaks the post loop and no content displays....

Comment: @jkendall Sorry, there was a typo. I accidentally typed a semicolon to much. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code that I'm using which seems to be working perfectly thanks!

```
    <?php
global $post;
$url = ((filter_var(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'RSS', true))) ? get_post_meta($post->ID, 'RSS', true) : 'ENTER FALL BACK URL HERE');
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load($url);
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node)
{
    $item = array(
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    );
    array_push($feed, $item);
}
$limit = 6;
for ($x = 0; $x < $limit; $x++)
{
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    echo '<div class="product-item">';
    echo '<p>' . $description . '</p>';
    echo '<p><strong><a href="' . $link . '" title="' . $title . '">' . $title . '</a></strong><br />';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```